# Numerical linear algebra: how to compute $B^TC^{−1}B$ efficiently

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-optimization, oc.optimization-and-control

Hi,

my question is similar to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73028/numerical-linear-algebra-how-to-compute-bta-1b-efficiently) one. I have to compute $B^TC^{−1}B$, where $C$ is a strictly positive definite $n\times n$ matrix and $B$ is $n\times m$.
The matrix $C$ is huge ($n$ up to a hundred thousand) and sparse. If $m$ is small I compute $b^TC^{−1}b$ for all columns $b$ of $B$ using CG which is really fast (much faster than Cholesky decomposition). However this becomes problematic if $m$ gets larger.

Are there methods from numerical optimization to compute $B^TC^{−1}B$ more efficient?

Thank you very much!

Manuel

Comment: It's no clear what you mean by "solve... directly". Do you mean "compute"?

Comment: @Dima Pasechnik: Yes, I changed it to make it clear

Comment: I would suggest first check what is wrong with CG. If for the bigger systems, it takes the similar number of iterations to convergence compared to the smaller system, then I don't know anything you can do about it. But if the bigger system takes a lot more iterations, you should look for additoinal structures of the system and find a good preconditioner.