# Inverse of a small submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse

Let $A$ be a large matrix (say, $1000 \times 1000$), and let $\mathcal I = \{2,3,5\}$ be a set of row/column indices. Let $(A^{-1})_{\cal I \times I}$ denote the submatrix of $A^{-1}$ that consists of the $\{2,3,5\}$ rows and columns of $A^{-1}$.

Is there an efficient way of computing the following $3 \times 3$ matrix inverse $((A^{-1})_{\cal I \times \cal I})^{-1}$ without inverting the large matrix $A$?

Comment: Couldn't you use Cramer's rule?

Comment: @abnry one can also use Cramer's rule here, if the determinant of $A$ is known (which presumably is not known here).

Comment: possibly related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73028/numerical-linear-algebra-how-to-compute-bta-1b-efficiently

Answer (score 11):

One way to go about this is as follows:

For $i,j \in \mathcal{I}$ Compute $e_i^TA^{-1}e_j$ by using the approach based on Gaussian quadrature; see for instance, a precise algorithm and analysis in our paper ["Gauss quadrature for matrix inverse forms with applications."](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01904)

Now that you have $[A^{-1}]_{\mathcal{I},\mathcal{I}}$, getting its inverse is an easy matter since $|\mathcal{I}|$ is small.

Comment: Interesting paper! Does this approach work in the case of indefinite or nonsymmetric matrices?

Comment: @Mahdi indefinite should be easy as long as symmetry / hermitian property is preserved (by adding $\lambda I$ to the matrix to ensure psd-ness for sufficiently large $\lambda$); for non-symmetric matrices, I don't recall an obvious idea right away, but you may find more related work e.g., on N. Higham's page: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/papers/

Answer (score 4):

Let me denote $B=A^{-1}$. The question is how to efficiently compute the inverse of a submatrix of $B$ given the fact that the inverse of the full matrix $B$ is known (since $B^{-1}=A$). An efficient algorithm for this task is given in [Relationship between the Inverses of a Matrix and a Submatrix.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f7c7/f9199da2a04111f0a7313e0f3f7e2a6a4d8c.pdf)

Comment: When $| \cal I| \sim 1000$, the method seems efficient. But what if $| \cal I| \ll 1000$ ? In this example, $| \cal I| = 3 \ll 1000$.